# Return AspNet Core Ident authentication state from new web app back to legacy Windows app during migration

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, access-token, asp.net-core-identity

First module in migration of click-once windows app to Blazor server is working well. Upgraded authentication from AspNetDB to AspNetCoreIdentDB. Now would like to point legacy app to new authentication model while huge task of migrating rest of code is underway. I can get to my web app login page from the legacy code, but can I safely return an authentication token? Closest thing I found was a message queue. Many thanks.

Comment: See following page.  It is different for Core 3.1 vs Core 6.0.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for this. I would prefer to use the latest version to maximize shelf life but I am willing to move up in steps if it helps with the migration. I will review this link and let you know.

Comment: The pulldown on upper left of pages has multiple versions so you can pick version you want.  Example code is different depending on version.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have abandoned this approach and I will eventually modify the authentication code in the original app without trying to reuse this interface.